# node.js | как заархивировать папку?

Tags: node.js, express

Делаю что то наподобие яндекс диска и столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Если пользователь захочет скачать папку, ее надо заархивировать и отправить.
Как сделать это через стримы, чтобы вышло что то такое?

```js
fs.createReadStream(folderToGet).turnItToZip().pipe(res) // sendFile
```

Было бы очень хорошо обойтись без сторонних библиотек

Answer (score 0):

Сразу прошу не пинать, не проверяю, у Вас будет возможность доработать лично ))

Сжатие есть без сторонних либ

```
const fs = require('fs');
const zlib = require('zlib');
const archiver = require('archiver');
```

Путь к папке

```
const folderToGet = '/path/to/folder';
```

Создай поток для записи архива

```
const archive = archiver('zip', { zlib: { level: 9 } });
archive.on('warning', err => {
  if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
    console.warn('Warning:', err.message);
  } else {
    throw err;
  }
});
archive.on('error', err => {
  throw err;
});
```

Собери всё что в папке в архив

```
const files = fs.readdirSync(folderToGet);
files.forEach(file => {
  const filePath = folderToGet + '/' + file;
  archive.file(filePath, { name: file });
});
```

Отправляем не глядя )

```
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=archive.zip');
res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/zip');
archive.pipe(res);
archive.finalize();
```

Comment: а не слишком опрометчиво пробегатся по файлам в папке, там ведь и вложенные папки могут быть?

Comment: Ну, во-первых, таких уточнений в вопросе не было, во-вторых, Вы можете это обработать нужным Вам образом